# XMLHttpRequest Open and Send: How to tell if it worked

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

As is in the title, my question is, Is is possible to tell if the open and send methods from XMLhttpRequest actually worked?  Is there any indicator? 
example code:

```
cli = new XMLHttpRequest();
cli.open('GET', 'http://example.org/products');
cli.send();
```

I'm trying to code in fault handling to this, but I need to be able to tell if the request failed so I can handle it.

Comment: Yes. It is. **What online resources/documentation that explain how to use XHR have been consulted? -1**; read a few, then, if there are remaining unclear points, ask a more directed question. (I would recommend using an XHR wrapper, but it's the same idea.)

Comment: @pst It seems to me that the asynchronous nature of the operation may legitimately be hard to understand by a newcomer who thus could be blocked. That's the reason why I answered. Do you think I shouldn't have done it ?

Comment: @dystroy Except for the fact this is a *well covered use case* .. people wrote documentation/tutorials for a reason.

Comment: Sorry I was just learning from http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp and i didnt realize that the ready state was in the hundreds and that it was updated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an an asynchronous operation. Your script continues its execution while the request is being sent.

You detect the state changes using a callback :

```
var cli = new XMLHttpRequest();
cli.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (cli.readyState === 4) {
            if (cli.status === 200) {
                       // OK
                       alert('response:'+cli.responseText);
                       // here you can use the result (cli.responseText)
            } else {
                       // not OK
                       alert('failure!');
            }
        }
};
cli.open('GET', 'http://example.org/products');
cli.send();
// note that you can't use the result just here due to the asynchronous nature of the request
```

Answer (score -1):

```
req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.onreadystatechange = dataLoaded;
req.open("GET","newJson2.json",true);
req.send();

function dataLoaded()
{
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // io error
    }
}
```