# How do I process an element returned by AJAX XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to AJAX and Javascript and I'm having an issue trying to reach an element returned by a AJAX XMLHttpRequest.

The scenario is as follows:

I fetch a table from another website, and after it is printed in my page using send() method, I want to access its elements. I figured out why I can NOT do it thanks to [dystroy's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11351773/2034041). I searched through stackoverflow and google but I was not able to find anything useful. In the case I missed the answer I'm seeking, I should apologize for the duplicate post.

So my question is: Since I cannot use the result just after the fetch code due to asynchronous nature of the request, what is the way to access the fetched elements just after the request?

Thank you for your attention & help:)

Edit: Context

Basically I fetch a table, write it into specified `<div>` element (#table) and then filter its contents and my aim here is now to write it into the other specified `<div>` element (#dersler) and then hide the columns other than the 2nd column only. The problem I am facing is as mentioned above that I cannot reach the table element which is just fetched.

here is the code:

```
function fetchPage(str)
        {
            if(str=="")
            {
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML="";
                $('#saatler').val(1);   //some filtering configuration
                $('#gunler').val(1);    //resetting filters in other words
                $('#bolumler').val(1);
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            else // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("dersler").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                        
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch.php?url=http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb="+str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            $('#saatler').val(1);   //some filtering configuration
            $('#gunler').val(1);    //resetting filters in other words
            $('#bolumler').val(1);

            //after fetch, new filter
             $("#dersler").find('table').css("background-color", "blue");
        }
```

Right now I am just trying to color its background blue. The problem is when I fetch the page, the already existing table which was created for testing is filled with blue, but after 500ms or so, the new table is overwritten onto the existing example table and the new table's background isn't filled with blue.

Comment: You have to show us some code, as your questions stands the answer is simply "Yes there is."  We need context to help you if you can't get it to work.

Comment: sorry about that, context added.

Comment: I see that you are using jQuery, why don't you use the `$.ajax()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform more actions after the return simply add that functionality in the callback function.  From your code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     document.getElementById("dersler").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                        
     // Add lots of good stuff here!!
   }
}
```

---

**Here is another style which might be clearer**

```
function fetchPage(str)
{
   // other stuff removed to save space

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=postCallack;

   xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch.php?url=http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb="+str, true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   // any stuff that goes here will happen before callback
   //  (this is a good place to update a UI element showing a call is resolving.)
   //  (for example a spinner or text saying "fetching")

}

function postCallback()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("dersler").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                        

    // continue to process post callback.
    $('#saatler').val(1);   //some filtering configuration
    $('#gunler').val(1);    //resetting filters in other words
    $('#bolumler').val(1);

    //after fetch, new filter
    $("#dersler").find('table').css("background-color", "blue");
  }
  else {
    // report error with fetch
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. haha that was easy:) Obviously, i did not get the nature of the code since I'm an absolute beginner:) I have a question though. Since I'm sort of used to sequential programming, I thought xmlhttp.send() did the fetching (I copied the code block from another source btw). Actually it does the fetching but why would anyone prefer to write it after the onreadystatechange ? Is there a good reason for that?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli - This is the way "callbacks" and "async" communication work.  Do some searches on these terms and it will clear it up.  One sentence try >> Control is passed away from your program (to do other things) while the communication resolves, the operating system (browser) thus needs an entry point (function) to call when the response arrives.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli - See my answer for an example of another to format your code which might be clearer.

Comment: Lovely structure @Hogan:) I had trouble with the error handling part, i.e. `else` block. The problem is, ERROR is displayed between the request initialization and response being ready states, i.e. while fetching. How can i resolve the issue? I can only display error at the correct time when i get a 404 error as listed in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp). I want my page to display error, say, when there is no connection, when theres a connection timeout etc. How can I manage it?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli - I would have to see the code you are using if you are having the symptom you describe.  It may be this should be a new question, because questions are not supposed to be back-and-forth on SO.  Also, this >> http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Thank you for the w3 warning, ill go through it. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715866/how-to-handle-xhr-error-display-messages) my new question if you feel like checking it out:)