# How to handle XHR error display messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to fetch some content from another source using XHR as shown below:

```
function fetchPage(str)
{
    if(str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML="";
        resetFilters();
        $('#progress').hide();  //fetching progress bar <div>
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=postCallback;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch.php?url=http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

// any stuff that goes here will happen before callback
//  (this is a good place to update a UI element showing a call is resolving.)
//  (for example a spinner or text saying "fetching")
$('#progress').show();
progressFetching();
switch(xmlhttp.readyState){ //loading bar adjustments
    case 0:
        $('.bar').css("width","0%");
        $('.bar').text("0%");
        break;
    case 1:
        $('.bar').css("width","25%");
        $('.bar').text("25%");
        break;
    case 2:
        $('.bar').css("width","50%");
        $('.bar').text("50%");
        break;
    case 3:
        $('.bar').css("width","75%");
        $('.bar').text("75%");
        break;
}
}



function postCallback()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    progressDone();   //loading is finished
    $('#error').hide();
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                     

    // continue to process post callback.
    resetFilters();
}
else {
    // report error with fetch

    /*if(xmlhttp.status==404 || xmlhttp.responseText == "")
        $('#error').show();*/
    //$('#error').show();
}
}
```

I want my page to display error when connection timeout occurs, or when the computer doesn't have an internet connection (maybe a disconnection occurred while hanging around) or any other situation where the webpage fails to fetch the contents of the other source.

Using the code above, in the `else` block, if I go for `if(xmlhttp.status==404 || xmlhttp.responseText == "")` in the `/* */` comment section, I won't get an error unless its not a 404 error. If i go for `//` comment section, error will be displayed after the fetching process is started until it is completed, i.e. between `xmlhttp.readyState = 0` through `xmlhttp.readyState = 4`. How can I display connection error messages using these attributes or something else?

Thank your for your attention:)

Comment: Since you've already got jQuery in place, why don't you use jQuery for XHR handling? It's way easier and probably fixes some cross browser issues you didn't think of (yet).

Comment: I think you are using jQuery, if that is that case check out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and take a look at the "error" parameter (don't reprogram what you already have)

Comment: I'm new at this, thank you for your suggestions:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is my template in prior question was flawed.  I believe this will work better because it creates a closure to pass the variable you need to work with.

Once again, I did not test this so it might have typos and bugs -- nor did I change anything except how `postCallback()` is invoked and added a parameter to it.

```
function fetchPage(str)
{
    if(str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML="";
        resetFilters();
        $('#progress').hide();  //fetching progress bar <div>
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function () { postCallback(xmlhttp); };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch.php?url=http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

// any stuff that goes here will happen before callback
//  (this is a good place to update a UI element showing a call is resolving.)
//  (for example a spinner or text saying "fetching")
$('#progress').show();
progressFetching();
switch(xmlhttp.readyState){ //loading bar adjustments
    case 0:
        $('.bar').css("width","0%");
        $('.bar').text("0%");
        break;
    case 1:
        $('.bar').css("width","25%");
        $('.bar').text("25%");
        break;
    case 2:
        $('.bar').css("width","50%");
        $('.bar').text("50%");
        break;
    case 3:
        $('.bar').css("width","75%");
        $('.bar').text("75%");
        break;
}
}



function postCallback(xmlhttp)
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    progressDone();   //loading is finished
    $('#error').hide();
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                     

    // continue to process post callback.
    resetFilters();
}
else {
    // report error with fetch

    /*if(xmlhttp.status==404 || xmlhttp.responseText == "")
        $('#error').show();*/
    //$('#error').show();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hogan, I worked it out by modifying it a little. I have seen the problem and changed the function as you suggested. Here is the resulting code 
`if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText != ""){` and `else {
        $('#progress').hide();
        $('#error').show();
        }` Everything seems to work as i desired. Is it good programming though? Thanks:)

Answer (score 9):

According to this stackoverflow: [XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866761/xmlhttprequest-error)

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
     if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
       console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
     } else {
       console.log("Error", xmlhttp.statusText)
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This does not help because this example is inline and his example is external which is where the problem is.